# Item realized event does not fire

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-8

Quick question about the Item realization event in `WP8`.

Here is my event registration which I call in the `ctor` for the View.

```
EpisodeList.ItemRealized += EpisodeList_ItemRealized;
```

Also here is my EventHandler

```
private void EpisodeList_ItemRealized(object sender, ItemRealizationEventArgs e)
{
        if (!vm.Loading && EpisodeList.ItemsSource != null && EpisodeList.ItemsSource.Count >= _offset)
        {
            if (e.ItemKind == LongListSelectorItemKind.Item)
            {
                if ((e.Container.Content as Medium).Equals(EpisodeList.ItemsSource[EpisodeList.ItemsSource.Count - _offset]))
                {
                    //Ask Messenger to notify the ViewModel To Load More Items
                    Messenger.Default.Send<MainPageLoadMoreEpisodesMessage>(new MainPageLoadMoreEpisodesMessage());
                }
            }
        }
}
```

My problem is that the event handler fires a few times but then it never fires again, I have no clue why I event tried to register the event handler again after loading was complete, I am unable to get the event handler to fire again.

Answer (score 0):

LongListSelctor Item Realized & Item Unrealized event fires when longlistselector scroll down or top, it take 20 element to realize at once, to fire it again it need more than 20 item in list. It don't need to register twice.

Comment: Thanks, but I have found another way to get this to work better, there is a ListView implementation by Kinnara, its much better I think.